# I want to Uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 From A Dual Boot With Windows 8 Consumer Preview?

Tags: windows

Last time I did this I was on windows 7 so I just repaired the MBR with EasyBCD but when I try there is no option for Windows 8, Only Windows 7.

So my question is how do I repair the MBR without the installation CD.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ] to see what kind of questions you can ask here. Regards.

Comment: While this is off-topic here, you can try http://superuser.com for more help. It helps with computer hardware and software, irrespective of operating system.

Comment: Related: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 2):

Consumer preview will expire.  Without legitimate installation media you are out of luck.

You could add a small /boot partition and use that to keep grub in tact without using Ubuntu until such time as you purchase Windows 8.

Sounds Off-topic to me though (I have a Windows 8 problem and no installation media).